# How to get all the texts displayed on a Web Page using Robot Framework?

Tags: java, python, angularjs, robotframework, selenium2library

I'm using Robotframework to automate tests, it uses the Selenium2 Library and gives the opportunity to extend many libraries (Java, Python, AngularJS, etc.).

Here's my question.

Is there a way to get all the texts displayed on a page?

I can get any specific text by the element locator, but currently I need to write a function which gets all the texts displayed on the page.

Does anyone know a way? Or a hint how to get things going?

Comment: You can get entire page's source code and then work with that: http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Get%20Source

Comment: Thanks Jan Kovařík!
I think That'll do the trick!

Comment: @JanKovařík 
I got the source by the following:

`${src}=    Selenium2Library.Get Source
OperatingSystem.Create File    ${OUTPUT_DIR}/source.html   ${src}`

Now can't figure how to get the texts from the source.
Any ideas about that? 

Thanks

Comment: Depends on your actual html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by getting the text content of the `<body>` tag:

```
${text}=  Get Text  //body
Log       ${text}    # a very long string, with newlines as delimiters b/n the different tags
${text as list}=  Split To Lines  ${text}
Log       ${text as list}   # a list, each member is the different tag's text
```

---

Another (non-working with SE) way to do it is to go after each element, with a locator like `//body//*`, producing webelements with `Get Webelements` on it.
But when you call`Get Text` on each produced webelement, it will return its text, plus the ones for all its children - thus duplicating the data. That can be done in pure xpath/xslt (with `text()`, `.` and `normalize-space()`), but regretfully not through webdriver/selenium (it always expects a node as argument).
The purpose of that ^ de-tour from the answer was to present the outcome of a 2 minute research :), and to get any feedback from someone that might have actually accomplished it with `Get Text` on each element of the page.